# What is Use of MATLAB or Matlab Tools in website development?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Can I use MATLAB for website development?
I want to embed image processing into C#.net web application. 
If any other tool used for website development.

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create CGI files that could be called by a web server. Have a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2YVMOV/) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-30REEY/).

EDIT:

I was thinking about this more and I think that you could also use matlab for web applications through python. Specifically,  [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/) would give very nice interface to matlab. mlabwrap is very good, i personally use it to access matlab from python. Thus you could build web app using python's pylons or django and access matlab through  mlabwrap.

Comment: for example suppose that I have code about image processing in matlab code used for remove blur from image etc..  and I want to use this to .Net web application. How I achieve it.. ?

Comment: @Abhishek. In .Net I don't know. Maybe there is something like mlabwrap in .Net?

Comment: This would be in  violation of Matlabs license - it is not permitted to allow people to use any form of interactive matlab without them having a user license. The only way around this is to use the Matlab compiler. (Ran into this problem in a large e-science project - the only way to offer matlab services is to pre-compile them). You might be better off just using Python + Numpy + Matplotlib which is unencumbered and should be easy to link to your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Matlab Builder NE, a Mathworks product for creating .Net components that might be perfect to integrate with your .Net web app:

http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/

No personal experience with this, but it sounds like something that would suit your needs perfectly.